# Failure on inclusion of bash_aliases on bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint

Might be unrelated background: Before upgrading Mint from 18 to 20.1 this problem not happening.

I have list of aliases in `/home/enter/.bash_aliases`. I can use those aliases as a normal user, but I want have it too when I am using root.

Someone tell that `.bash_aliases` is being included by default, but the fact it's not when using root (using sudo -su).

By some comment on bashrc [sample](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html), I made addition on `~/.bashrc` (/home/enter/.bashrc):

```
if [ -f /home/enter/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . /home/enter/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Could you help to locate where is the mistake?
Those aliases not available when using root.
A clear explanation is another niceness :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error of some sort? By `~/.bashrc`, do you mean your `/home/enter/.bashrc` or `/root/.bashrc`?

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you are "using root" - via `su`? via `sudo`? If the latter, then the difference in behavior between versions may be the result of changes in sudo's default `set_home` configuration

Comment: Q updated, oh man @ muru already give some clue. @steeldriver ah that makes me more confused, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do `source .bash_aliases`, simple explanation already on [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do#:%7E:text=source%20is%20a%20bash%20shell,(period).)